# Unity www.uploadProgress jumps from 0 to 100 in build but works fine on editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, upload

all!

Im trying to monitor the progress of the file I'm uploading. In Unity editor, it works fine. You can it climb from 0 to 100. But when I build it on my phone, it goes from 0 straight to 100.

Here is my code

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddBinaryData("image", image_bytes);
using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("mylink.com/post", form))
{
   www.SendWebRequest();
   while (!www.isDone)
   {
       float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(www.uploadProgress / 0.9f)
       progress = Mathf.Round(progress * 100);
       Debug.Log("Upload Progress : " + progress + "%");
       yield return null;  
   }

   Debug.Log("Success");
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's very fast that you don't even see the upload. Try to upload more files and see what happens. It will also be helpful to mention your Unity version and the platform you are building for that's not working.

Comment: @Programmer i'm currently building for iOS and i'm running Unity 2017.2.0f3